# Allow LAN clients to sync time through DD-WRT

Tags: ntp, dd-wrt

I'm having problems when syncing time trough DD-WRT. I have multiple LAN clients and none of them seems to be able to sync time with an internet time server. I have a TP-Link WR1043ND that does this nicely, but my WRT54GL flashed with DD-WRT doesn't do this. How can I enable it?

Comment: The only reason this won't work is if you've either set a default deny and not permitted 123/UDP or if you've explicitly blocked 123/UDP.

Comment: WRT54GL has factory settings. As far as I understand I need to do some IPTables voodoo?

Comment: What version of DD-WRT? I see that on old v23sp2 there is no ntp server at all.

Comment: Yep, v23sp2. Can I just allow udp/123 packets to travel through the router to LAN clients? And if yes, how?